# Highlight today in Mac's cal

Tags: sed, date, cal

Every Mac comes with `cal` which shows a simple calendar of current month. Output is something like this:

```
   February 2014
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
                   1
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21 22
23 24 25 26 27 28
```

I was wondering if we can use some `sed` and `date` magic and highlight today's number using ANSI escape sequences. I haven't tried anything because I don't know much about `sed`.

Comment: `cal` from bsdmainutils 8.2.3 already seems to be highlighting the current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ cal | grep -w -A4 -B6 $(date +%d)
```

`-A4` and `-B6` flags of `grep` will print 4 lines after and 6 lines before the matching line.

Comment: This didn't work for me. For today, it printed this: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=gt0FrjF3

Comment: I tried this: `cal | grep -A4 -B5  --color "\s$(date +%d)\s"` and gave me good results. But I'm not sure if that works for first day of month or alike

Comment: @Mohsen Updated answer. This should work for all days.

Comment: Ok, works good now. You might want to add `--color` flag because Mac's grep don't highlight by default

Comment: @Mohsen Thanks for the update. On my mac, I do not seem to need the  `--color` flag. It works as it is.

Answer (score 4):

`gcal`(http://www.gnu.org/software/gcal/) is available from Homebrew and displays the current month with current day highlighted when invoked without any other args.